# Winedt compilation problem

Tags: compiling, winedt

I have a file in LaTeX format. The problem is the file does not accept any changes in the text and gives the same PDF file. I have used Winedit to compile it but the same problem occurs. Please see if you can overcome this technical issue.

The log file say:

```
Errors were reported during the execution of PDFTeXify.
*** WinEdt captured the following error file:

Running pdftex...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.8-beta-20080627 (MiKTeX 2.7) (INITEX)

entering extended mode

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\config\pdflatex.ini"

("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.7\tex\generic\c

onfig\pdftexconfig.tex")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\00miktex\texsys.cfg")

./texsys.aux found





\@currdir set to: ./.





Assuming \openin and \input 

have the same search path.





Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.



catcodes, registers, compatibility for TeX 2,  parameters,



!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

! You are attempting to make a LaTeX format from a source file

! That is more than five years old.

!

! If you enter <return> to scroll past this message then the format

! will be built, but please consider obtaining newer source files

! before continuing to build LaTeX.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!



! LaTeX source files more than 5 years old!.

l.545 ...aTeX source files more than 5 years old!}



!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Transcript written on pdflatex.log.

makefmt: pdftex failed on pdflatex.ini.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason.


*** WinEdt captured the following console output:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.8-beta-20080627 (MiKTeX 2.7)
I can't find the default format file!


*** BibTeX did not produce a log file "_temp.blg"!

*** MakeIndex did not produce a log file "_temp.ilg"!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Perhaps another main file is defined in WinEdt, and it launches the compiler on this other file? What does the log file say?

Comment: Another possibility: WinEdt launches the compiler on another copy of your file and, this copy not being modified, the resulting .pdf isn't modified either.

Comment: @Bernard: I add the message of the log file in the question.

Comment: @zeraoulia: the first thing to is updating MiKTeX: you use version 2.7 (end-of-life: 2/17/2007!). LaTeX has changed a lot since then, and it would be a loss of time to try make it work. You should download the basic installer, and update or download packages  you need that aren't in the basic installation progressively. Keep the old version for some time until you're sure version 2.9 works fine.

Comment: Something is very seriously wrong. It is hard to know what exactly. Is the file you are trying to compile supposed to produce a document? Because pdfTeX is not running in a mode which might do that. It seems to be running in the mode it uses to generate format files (`.fmt`) which are then used when compiling documents. At least, that is how it looks. Since you should certainly update anyway, that is surely the best option.

Comment: @Bernard: I' ve tried to  install MiKTeX 2.9 but the log file says: An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
  source line: 308
  message: The operation failed for some reason.
  info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe